# Jersey ContainerRequestFilter causes MarshallingException

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0, java-io, moxy

I created a new ContainerRequestFilter to print out any new request payloads that coming in, but only if the HTTP server was started with the `DEBUG_MODE` argument. When I send a request to my REST resource while not in `DEBUG_MODE`, everything works fine. 
When this filter executes:

```
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.USER)
public class InboundDebugFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

  @Override
  public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
    if (AuthorizationMain.DEBUG_MODE) {
      System.out.println("New request at: " + requestContext.getUriInfo().getRequestUri().toString());
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(requestContext.getEntityStream(), "utf-8"));
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      String line;
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line).append("\n");
      }
      br.close();
      System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following long stacktrace **AFTER** the 2 print lines execute just fine in this filter (but before the code gets to my resource class):

```
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 400 Bad Request
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider.readFrom(MOXyJsonProvider.java:708)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.invokeReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:155)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:74)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:155)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1085)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:874)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest.readEntity(ContainerRequest.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.EntityParamValueFactoryProvider$EntityValueFactory.provide(EntityParamValueFactoryProvider.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParamValueFactoryWithSource.provide(ParamValueFactoryWithSource.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:127)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:384)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler$1.run(HttpHandler.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-25004] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: An error occurred unmarshalling the document
Internal Exception: javax.json.JsonException: I/O error while parsing JSON]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.handleXMLMarshalException(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:1072)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.unmarshal(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider.readFrom(MOXyJsonProvider.java:660)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-25004] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: An error occurred unmarshalling the document
Internal Exception: javax.json.JsonException: I/O error while parsing JSON
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException.unmarshalException(XMLMarshalException.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.json.JsonStructureReader.parse(JsonStructureReader.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:978)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:425)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:708)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLUnmarshaller.unmarshal(XMLUnmarshaller.java:643)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.unmarshal(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:339)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: javax.json.JsonException: I/O error while parsing JSON
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonTokenizer.read(JsonTokenizer.java:444)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonTokenizer.nextToken(JsonTokenizer.java:354)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonParserImpl$NoneContext.getNextEvent(JsonParserImpl.java:222)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonParserImpl$StateIterator.next(JsonParserImpl.java:172)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonParserImpl.next(JsonParserImpl.java:149)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonReaderImpl.read(JsonReaderImpl.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.json.JsonStructureReader.parse(JsonStructureReader.java:139)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NIOInputStreamImpl.read(NIOInputStreamImpl.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.EntityInputStream.read(EntityInputStream.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream.read(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:296)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonTokenizer.fillBuf(JsonTokenizer.java:473)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonTokenizer.read(JsonTokenizer.java:434)
    ... 44 more
```

I'm not sure what causes the problem here, any tips?

Comment: A stream can only be read once. If you read it in the filter, then the MessageBodyReader has nothing to read. This is probably causing the exception. If you are going to read the stream in the filter, then you should reset it with requestContext.setEntityStream.

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem. Wanna post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stream can only be read once. If you read it in the filter, then the `MessageBodyReader` has nothing to read. This is probably causing the exception. If you are going to read the stream in the filter, then you should reset it with `requestContext.setEntityStream`.